# Can't download or upload with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, files, downloads, browser, upload

I'm new to Linux, and this might seem ridiculous to ask. Whenever I press to upload or download a file from Chrome, the Files window seems to appear outside reach, which precludes me from selecting the file or the directory. How can I bring it in reach? If I go to the top left corner and click activities, I can see the Files window is there together with the browser, but it's unreachable.

Answer (score 2):

you can try to 'detach' the file browser dialogbox from the main window
type this command in a termnial
you can rollback by entering the same command with false replacing true...

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter attach-modal-dialogs false
```

Comment: That worked: I was able to grab and drag the window within range. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark as solved.

Comment: @cmak.fr Do you know the solution for this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1121323/i-am-unable-to-save-files-from-libreoffice-and-web-browser