# I am unable to save files from LibreOffice and Web Browser

Tags: upgrade, mount, fstab

Update:
*It has been marked duplicate of another fstab question which I have checked. There it is about external drive but for me, write permission from Browsers and LibreOffice is not working on any places of my hard drive. Also, I write using touch at any places and partition I want. In /dev/sda8, which I have added are also writable using `touch` using command line.*

I recently upgraded Ubuntu to 18.04. After that I changed fStab file for making a partition self mount. While playing when I changed UUID based to /dev/sda8 I made mistake. Then I was sent to emmergency mode where only command line was there. From there, I used `$sudo mount -o remount,rw /` 
Then I could correct mistake in fstab.
This made all fine.

But later I saw Libreoffice and two browsers cannot save files. Web browsers (Chrome and FF) cannot save image. and LibreOffice do not allow me to save any newly created files. 
I see no input box to enter name of files from Libreoffice and browser when I go to save. I can browse files there when I go to save.

Please help.

(I was earlier into web dev but I am out from few years. So, please do not go by my points here.)

Update as per comment:

```
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=b420475d-e47a-4e27-bbdc-61f3e1b767af /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
#UUID=1E62-A9A6  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=0e2b4f4e-7972-4811-90e1-f693618d7588 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=58a9292f-a7a7-403d-b5e9-126fc659f678 none            swap    sw              0       0
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=b8c998af-60bf-4b40-92da-e7ab29608c64 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=1E62-A9A6  /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0   1
# Shared is a common dir
/dev/sda8 /media/mt-pt-shared ntfs defaults 0 0
```

Also, I just found that I cannot even save to pen drive from browser.

**Update: Mar 4, 2019**

1) Just to check, I uninstalled libreoffice using interface and later installed using command-line. But, no use.

2) 
This is the save dialog I got when I pressed Ctrl + S in Chrome:
[image]
While trying to add pic here from Chrome browser, I saw, I cannot even upload pic from Chrome. So, I tried drag and that has worked.

**Update: As requested by 'cmak.fr'**

```
$ cat .config/user-dirs.dirs
```

Output:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop" 
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

---

```
$ cat /etc/mtab | grep '/dev/sd'
```

Output:

```
/dev/sda2 / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/sda4 /home ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/sda8 /media/mt-pt-shared fuseblk rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
/dev/sda1 /boot/efi vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 0
```

---

```
$ df -Th | grep -v fs
```

Output:

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2      ext4       46G  9.4G   34G  22% /
/dev/sda4      ext4      184G  3.3G  171G   2% /home
/dev/sda8      fuseblk   345G   23G  323G   7% /media/mt-pt-shared
/dev/sda1      vfat      476M  8.5M  467M   2% /boot/efi
```

**Note**: In comment, I have mentioned that I can create file without any difficulty using gEdit. And also, using right click - create file. screenshot-tool can also save new file easily without any problem.

**Update: Mar 7, 2019**
I have tried uninstalling with `purge --autoremove`, switching to older generic 4.10 or something,whatever was available. Also chmod, etc which I am not very sure, if I have done correctly.
Also, tried to see after stopping AppArmor as suggested here in comment.

*I forgot to mention that in my Laptop after Upgrade, when I try to go to Setting for anything from 'Show Application' then it crash. I do not receive anything. No message also.*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90724/discussion-on-question-by-satya-prakash-i-am-unable-to-save-files-from-libreoffi).

Comment: If you can,  create another user, login to that user & see if things work properly there.

Comment: Ok. I have installed 18.10 and I am happy. Very good looking. No problem of this kind too. I think, I am going to install without LTS support in future. Latest is better. I have tried to solve this but could not get any clue from anywhere.
*Now, I may do not track it. Thank you all for your effort.*

Answer (score 0):

To debug, try launching one of the browsers from the command line and try saving something from the browser. Watch for error messages in the command-line terminal to see if you get any messages that indicate what the problem could be.

Also, just to make sure it's not a permissions issue, try launching LibreOffice Writer as the root user from the command line and try to save a file.

Comment: `launching LibreOffice Writer as the root user` this is an extremely bad idea

Comment: Watching for errors is a very good idea...

Comment: I have tried to play with chmod but not sure if that was correct. 
Tried your idea. 
LibreOffice can save new file.
FF say, it cannot start as Root in regular user's session. Not supported.

Comment: How can an upgrade and/or fStab or that secure mode change in BIOS can change permission!

Comment: It's not a solution yet but it's progress. It's looking like a permissions issue even if we can't explain why there would be a permissions issue. One more test: can LibreOffice save to a different device (not as root this time), say a USB device?

Comment: I used this solution for Libreoffice which provides permission but no use. https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/19549/office-permission/?answer=24619#post-id-24619 Also to reiterate that Abiword was not in my Ubuntu laptop so I thought to work with this meanwhile but no use. That was giving same issue.

Comment: Try running LibreOffice from the command line, but this time as your normal user (not root) and try to save. As before, watch the command line terminal for error messages.

Comment: New file save is still not working. Error:
(soffice:5647): Gtk-WARNING **: 20:07:26.290: (../../../../gtk/gtkicontheme.c:5497):gtk_icon_theme_lookup_by_gicon_for_scale: runtime check failed: ((flags & GTK_ICON_LOOKUP_GENERIC_FALLBACK) == 0)
Other similar errors.

Comment: I could be wrong that that kind of warning about the theme icon doesn't look like it's the issue. Do you get any actual errors?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90827/discussion-between-satya-prakash-and-eric-mintz).

Comment: Download from Browser works.